# List activity for all members (whether they have contributed or not)

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, civireport

Our treasurer has asked for a report to show the payment history for each contact, even if that contact has never paid anything.

'Contribution Aggregate by Relationship' report is perfect, we select all the relevant years and it presents the data beautifully but the problem is that it's only showing contacts who have made a contribution in one of the years selected. We need it to show a line of data for each member, regardless if they have paid or not.

'Contribution and Membership Detail' report also has the information needed albiet in a different format, but again, it only shows contacts who have made a contribution.

If there is a built-in report for the data we need, apologies, I'm struggling to find it.  Does anyone know if any of the civi extensions might do this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.pivotreport may help

Answer (score 1):

How comfortable are you with Excel? If you do your contribution aggregate and check the box for Contact ID as a column and then export the results, and then also do an export of all your members and also include contact id, then you can use excel to merge the two lists based on contact id.

Also unless you need the relationship you can also look at Search - Custom Searches - Contribution Aggregate which should be the same thing just in a less spread out format which would make it easier to work with in excel.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm comfortable with excel, thanks for the suggestion, but the person I'd be sending it too less so. Using your suggestion would buy me some time.

However, that means any time he needed updated data, we'd have to go through the same process, which wouldn't be ideal.

Thanks for the tip on the custom searches too, I'd don't need the relationship, but it shows the data I need (each year listed out).

Answer (score 0):

Not a coherent solution but maybe a feasible workaround: You could install the [civicrm summary fields extension](https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/) which provides aggregated contribution amounts in contact custom fields. You could then simply use a contact search & export or a report that includes those number.

However, you would only be able to pull data up to the fiscal year before last, unless you extend the extension [:)](https://imgflip.com/i/47pbfb)